# Which test would be appropriate for my data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spss

I did a questionnaire survey wherein I asked the respondents questions on their saving habits. One of the question had two options, either save formally or informally. These options has categories to choose from like follows
Q. Mode of saving
Formal
1. bank
2. property.
3. Gold
Informal
1. Cash
2. Informal groups
3. Buy livestock

The respondents can choose any option from these. 
I want to see the relationship of mode of saving with demographics.
What should be the appropriate method and statistical tool to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two logistic regressions. The first is a standard logistic regression with the two-option outcome as the response and the demographics as the predictors. This would allow you to answer the broader question of what kind of people prefer to save formally or informally. The second logistic regression would be a multinomial logistic regression with all the possibilities as the response and the demographics as the predictors. From this model, you could compare how different demographics predict choosing one option versus another or make predictions about how certain combinations of demographics choose to save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chi square test of independence or odds ratio